# Saving/Loading Sequentially Randomly Generated Levels

Tags: java, libgdx

I am in the process of developing a game with randomly generated levels.  The levels are randomly generated 2d "terrain" that appear continuous in that each one takes into account the last "height" value of the previous "level."  The levels are then loaded 5 at a time, where the 2nd level is the "current" level, the 1st level is the level that was just completed, and the 3-5th levels are there in case the user overshoots the "current" level.

I am using a seeded Random (Java.Util.Random) so that the randomly generated levels are consistently the same.  Level "1" is the same for everyone as everyone's Random object is seeded the same.  The issue  I'm having arises when I want everyone's level 500, or even 1000 to be the same.  Sure it would be nice for my game to be so addicting people play through 500 or 1000 levels in one sitting, but eventually the user will have to stop and I will have to save their process so they can load it up later.

At first I thought "oh why not just store the level number they are on" and when I load the levels I just keep generating them until I hit the number.  After testing that theory on my phone and waiting 5 minutes while the levels kept generating until they hit level 1000 I realized that was a silly, "ready, fire, aim" approach to doing this.

So my question is, is there a way to store "where" I am in a seeded Random object so that I can recreate the exact situation based on the "location" of the Random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can get a seed from a Random object.

However, I think that for your purposes, you can use the following class, which caches the seed, allowing you to call `getSeed()`

```
public class SeedGettableRandom {
    long seed;
    public SeedGettableRandom(long initialSeed) {
        this.seed = initialSeed;
    }
    public void nextBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        Random rand = new Random(seed);
        rand.nextBytes(bytes);
        seed = rand.nextLong();
    }
    // analogous methods for the rest of Random's methods.
    public long getSeed() {
        return seed;
    }
}
```

And of course, if performance is an issue, you can just put your entire thing into it's own method. E.g.:

```
public byte[][] nextGameTerrainData() {
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    // Do whatever you were doing with you Random object
    seed = rand.nextLong();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful, I am currently implementing a solution based on your answer and will hopefully get it up and running.  Unfortunately as this is a new account I cannot "Vote up" for you yet, but I will check you off once I make sure I can load/save properly.

Comment: Not quite working, perhaps I'm doing something wrong?  I pass to the generator Long.parseLong("11223344").  I then set a private variable Long seed = the passed long.  Then when the generator calls "generateMap" I first call rand = new Random(seed); and after finishing I call seed = rand.nextLong();  These are the seeds that get generated (...'s to save space):

Seed0: 11223344 -
Seed1: -139199... -
Seed2: 800030... -

Unfortunately, when I try passing -139199... to the generator I get this, which is not a continuation since Seed 1 below != seed 2 above: 
Seed0: -139199... - 
Seed1: 4722603...

Comment: Can you post what happens between seed 0 and seed 1 and seed 2?

Comment: Because if you seed a Random, it should be deterministic. Is the seed # itself included in your calculations? or is there some data included in your calculations that is not captured in the seed?

Comment: A lot happens between seed 0 and seed 1, I simplified things and added the Random to my MapManager class so we have Random rand = new Random(seed); seeds[0] = seed; maps[0] = generateMap(rand); seed = rand.nextLong(); WHICH IS FOLLOWED BY rand = new Random(seed); seeds[1] = seed; map[1] = generateMap(rand); seed = rand.nextLong(); ETC. SORRY FOR THE CAPS earlier I just wanted to differentiate what is code and what isn't.  Anyway, inside my generateMap function I have a bunch of rand.nextInt() calls but that's it.  Your logic makes a lot of sense and it's blowing my mind that it isn't working.

Comment: is the number of calls to `nextInt()` constant over the level number in `generateMap(rand)`? BTW, you can use the symbols `` (left of 1) to display code

Comment: I may have found the issue, in my generator function I have a `rand.nextInt()` call that is only called when it is the first map, otherwise it takes the height argument from the previous map.  I am going to work with this section now but it would make sense that this is the issue. EDIT: I'm an idiot, I misread the code formatting guide as apostrophe's.  Thank you for that!

Comment: There is a simple solution. Just call `nextInt()` even if you don't use it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you generate all the levels you need (randomly) at game start and then save the order? You can do that at start of the game. Then when player quits the game store current level order. When it continues load all saved levels and position you saved.

Comment: Theoretically this game can go forever, so there is an infinite number of levels I need.  K_G came up with a working algorithm that I am utilizing now.

Comment: That's the theory. Don't think that anyone will play more than i.e. 10 000 levels. :)